# CSS - the categories menu - the subcategory is not rendering properly

Tags: jquery, css

on [that](http://tinyurl.com/smooth-menu-example) page, I have the categories menu, I build it using the [jQuery SmoothMenu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm). The problem is, if it's container has the lower height than the currently's selected submenu (to see it, select the 2nd menu item), that submenu is not rendering properly. **I want to achieve, that oin that case the submenu extends beyond the container's border.** I have no idea how to fix that, I'll be grateful of any help

Comment: What do you want to happen if the menu is larger than the container? 2 super-simple fixes come to mind: 1 - Set a `min-height` on the content-middle wrapper (although it needs to be over 1000px to fix your problem). 2 - Split the menu up into smaller sub-menus. A menu with that many options is not user friendly, so you should really be doing this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the gap between the menu container and the menu items? This only seems to be an issue in IE (at least, Firefox was fine). It seems you're forcing the page into IE8 mode too from the source, if I manually override it to IE9 it's fine. That's a reasonably helpful place to start.

If you add the following CSS the vertical scroll bar is always shown, this stops the page jumping horizontally when you select a menu item which goes off screen and also seems to clear up the gap issue:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
```